# Buffer Until Intersection using ArcGiS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, buffer

I am trying to use ArcGIS ModelBuilder to create a toolbox that places a buffer of  1 mile around X location, but does not cross major highways. Effectively, I am geo-fencing in real estate comps.

In the model below, for every "active" (property in green) I put a 1 mile buffer to capture all properties "closed" (in blue), then use an intersection to exclude it from crossing the major highways and excluding and closed properties over the boundary.

Unfortunately, this does not work.

Any thoughts on the proper way to do this?

Here is an image of the roads or boundaries that I already have and do not want my buffers to cross.

[image: Data]

Here is an image of the current ModelBuilder I have, however it is wrong and does not work.

[image: Model]

Here is an image of just a standard 1 mile buffer around X point. [image]

Here is more closely what I am trying to accomplish. Essentially, the logic is buffer up to 1 mile or until you hit a major highway. [image]

Revised ModelBuilder using Smiller's comments
[image]

Results of revised ModelBuilder
[image]

Comment: David, Could you edit your question with a sketch of what your intended output would be, it is difficult to understand what your are trying to achieve with intersections, clips and buffers...

Comment: What license level do you have?  With Advanced license you could try: 1) create polygons from the road network (feature to polygon tool) 2) Create 1 mi buffer 3) intersect the two layers.  (Or the feature to polygon tool with both the streets and your 1mi buffer might work)

Comment: @Hornbydd I added two additional photos. One of a basic 1 mile buffer, then a second of what ideally I want to happen. Does that help? Essentially, the logic is buffer up to 1 mile or until you hit a major highway in all directions.

Comment: @smiller I tried as you mentioned. Active > 1 Mile Buffer with Roads Network > Feature to Polygon. Then intersect both of those and get a resulting intersecting polygon. It still just creates a standard 1 mile buffer with no regard for the road boundaries.

Comment: Could you post an example of the output from "feature to polygon" for the roads? Make sure you are including just the major roads (the road types that you want to be your cutoffs.)

Comment: @smiller Sorry I just meant that I created a 1 mile buffer around each of my green houses in the first image (4 green houses total). Then separately I create the feature to polygon directly from the roads network. Then I intersected both of these together. The result was a new shapefile that is virtually identical to just 4 standard 1 mile buffers around each green house. It didn't have any regard for the roads.

Comment: Please post examples. Also please confirm that the tool is not somehow using the wrong type of Intersect (should be the overlay tool version).

Comment: @smiller added photos to original post at the bottom showing the revised modelbuilder we discussed as well as the mapped result. The roads network feature to polygon basically is just the entire map, so that can't be right? You'll notice the final product of the intersect is basically just standard bufffer.

Comment: Your output of the intersect should be many individual polygons (turn on borders in display to view, or look at attribute table). One of the polygons is the interior road-limited buffer. You can figure out which one is the correct polygon via Select By Location.  Note: Since your active locations are near each other you have overlapping buffers; you may need to iterate through the buffers.

Comment: @smiller Ok I think I understand your general logic, but how should I change the model builder to achieve that? I see what you mean with the attribute table and the individual polygons. For example the FID that all of these active locations are in is "6708". I am just not sure how to structure it in the model itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the logic that will work on a selected point, you would attach it to an iterator if you wanted to do do all your "active" houses. I leave that for you to work out!

[image: Model]

Output would be:

[image: Output]

Things to note:

1. Houses have a field that distinguishes them, I simply added a field called type and called it *active*.
2. Houses are label points for the feature to polygon tool, this passes the *active* type value into the polygon. As only one polygon intersects a single point (active house) the others have activity of nothing and it is those that you delete.
3. The select by attribute is selecting all polygons that are not type *active*.
4. Roads do not need to be buffered they are simply the line network.

Comment: This looks promising! Will try shortly and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I have to work out some of the kinks and fine tune for my purposes. However, generally speaking this works perfectly and exactly as intended. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand your question completely. But as far as I understand, you could use the "near" function to calculate the minimum distance from every green point to the highway, then use this distance to create buffers?

Comment: I think that would just create smaller buffers right? If there is a highway .2 miles north of a green point then that would just create a .2 mile buffer around green. I neee it to create a polygon buffer where it may go .2 miles north because it stops at the highway, but still goes up to 1 mile in all other directions, unless it hits another highway boundary.